# How to upload tab delimited text file to Big Query when string field for column receives a parse error?

Tags: parsing, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, text-files, delimiter

I have a ~1 GB text file with 153 separate fields. I uploaded the file to GCS and then created a new table in BQ with file format as "CSV". For table type, I selected "native table". For schema, I elected to auto-detect. For the field delimiter, I selected "tab". Upon running the job, I received the following error:

*Could not parse '15229-1910' as INT64 for field int64_field_19 (position 19) starting at location 318092352 with message 'Unable to parse'*

The error is originating out of a "zip code plus 4" field. My question is if there is a way to prevent the field from parsing this value or if there's a way to omit these parse errors altogether so that the job can complete? From GCP's documentation, they advise "If BigQuery doesn't recognize the format, it loads the column as a string data type. In that case, you might need to preprocess the source data before loading it". The "zip code plus four" field in my file is already assigned as a string field type, therefore, I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Being that I selected the delimiter as "tab", does that indicate that the "zip code plus for" value contains a tab character?

Comment: This error can be avoided by editing the schema and checking that all the data in your file is valid. Could you provide sample data for zip code plus for?

Comment: This is an example of the data: "ALANOR" "E" "" "F" 02/19/1978 01/01/2000 "A" 02/03/2020 "D" "6226" "" "GARY ST" "" "" "SOUTH PARK" "PA" "15129-2312" "" "" "" "" "" 11/03/2020 "2050003" "2050003-1" 10/27/2020 "122152515" "2050003" ""  How can I go about cleaning this data and be able to pull it into bigquery?

Comment: I have replicated it by creating a table using sample data provided by you as a tab delimited text file and it was created successfully. The zip code is a string and it is getting parsed as a string in auto detect schema. If you are trying to parse the pincode as integer then this error occurs. Could you explain your issue? For cleaning the data you can check [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep) and [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm curious how you were able to accomplish generating a table. Each time I attempt to do so, it fails. I've tried using dataflow to convert the file to a.csv format but it still fails due to errors. Rather than using auto-detect for the schema, should I manually define each field? Would that fix this issue?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery uses [auto-detect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect) schema to detect the schema of a table while loading data into the BigQuery. As per the sample data provided by you, pincode will be considered as string value by BigQuery due to the presence of dash”-” in between the integer values. If you want to provide schema, you can avoid using auto-detect and give schema manually.

As stated in the comment, you can try this to upload your 1 GB text file into Bigquery by following the steps :

- As mentioned by you in the question assuming your data is in the CSV format.  From the given sample data, I have mocked the data in excel sheet.

**Excel Sheet**

[image]

- Save the file in .tsv format.
- You can upload the file into BigQuery using auto-detect schema and setting tab as delimiter. It will automatically detect all the field types without any error as can be seen in the table in BigQuery in the screenshot.

**BigQuery Table**

[image]